# How to create a side navbar in windows store app?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-mobile

I'm developing a laptop selling windows store app using c# and xmal and i want navbar its already Microsoft use in windows 8  bulletin app like News App , win 10 Cortana ..

User start the app i want to show the small nav like this demo img [Small Navbar Demo Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMl7m.jpg)

Click the toggle button display the big nav like this [Big Navbar Demo Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqYJt.jpg)

This is my second question in stackoverflow..

I hope in this time i get my answer..
Thanks to all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the SplitView Control (aka: Hamburger Menu), new XAML element comes with Windows 10..

**XAML Implementation :**

```
<SplitView x:Name="SplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="False">
    <SplitView.Pane>
       <!-- items -->
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <SplitView.Content>
        <!-- page/ content -->
    </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```

Here's great samples and guidelines about it:

http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2015/04/implementing-hamburger-button-with.html

http://igrali.com/2015/04/12/getting-started-with-splitview-control-in-universal-apps/

Comment: If this answer fits your needs, please accept it so we ensure that the case is closed :-)

Comment: sir needs help
[`Question`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839308/how-to-set-gridview-in-alphabetical-order-using-json-data-and-gridview-template)